# CodeIgniter 4 - Cannot submit data with TinyMCE text editor but with normal text area data gets submitted

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-applications, codeigniter-4, tinymce-5

I am trying to integrate TinyMCE editor with CodeIgniter 4 application. However the data from the tinyMCE textarea is not getting submitted to database even when i click on submit button but with normal textarea the data is submitted to database easily.

Also when i edit & update the submitted data, it gets updated in the database but the text formatting from tinyMCE is erased and data is saved as normal text in the database.

**Here is my code below**

**Add page controller**

```
public function addPage() {

    if(!session()->has('logged_staff')) {

            return redirect()->to(base_url(). "/team");
    
    } 
    $data = [];
    $data['validation'] = null;
    $suid = session()->get('logged_staff');
    $data['staffdata'] = $this->adminModel->getLoggedStaffData($suid);
    $data['memrole'] =  $this->adminModel->getMemberRole($suid);
    $data['permission'] = $this->adminModel->getPermission($suid);

    $checkPermission = $this->adminModel->checkPermission($suid);
    $memrank = $this->adminModel->getMemberRank($suid);

    if(is_array($memrank)) {

            if($memrank['rank'] == 'Super Admin') {

            }
            elseif(isset($checkPermission)) {
                    if($checkPermission['pages'] == 'Not Allowed') {
    
                            return redirect()->back();
    
                    }
            }
    }

    if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {

            $rules = [
                    'p_name' => [

                            'rules' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[250]',
                            'errors' => [
    
                                    'required' => 'You cannot leave this field empty',
                                    'min_length' => 'Title is short',
                                    'max_length' => 'Title is too long',
                            ]
                            ],
                    'p_description' => [
    
                            'rules' => 'required',
                            'errors' => [
    
                                    'required' => 'You cannot leave this field empty',
                            ]
                            ],
            ];

            if($this->validate($rules)) {

                    $addContent = [

                            'p_name'        => $this->request->getVar('p_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
                            'p_description' => htmlentities($this->request->getVar('p_description', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)),
                            'p_date'        => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
                            'p_slug'        => strtolower(url_title($this->request->getVar('p_name'))),

                    ];

                    if($this->pageModel->insertContent($addContent)) {

                            $this->session->setTempdata('success', 'Page updated successfully', 3);
                            return redirect()->to(base_url()."/admin/pages");

                    } else {

                            $this->session->setTempdata('error', 'Oops! could not update the page', 3);
                            return redirect()->to(current_url());

                    }
                    

            } else {

                    $data['validation'] = $this->validator;

           }

    } 

    echo view("team/Templates/header_panel");
    echo view("team/navigation", $data);
    echo view("team/sidebar", $data);
    echo view("team/addpage", $data);
    echo view("team/Templates/footer_panel");
    
}
```

**Edit Page Controller**

```
public function editPage($id=null) {

    if(!session()->has('logged_staff')) {

            return redirect()->to(base_url(). "/team");
    
    } 
    $data = [];
    $data['validation'] = null;
    $suid = session()->get('logged_staff');
    $data['staffdata'] = $this->adminModel->getLoggedStaffData($suid);
    $data['memrole'] =  $this->adminModel->getMemberRole($suid);
    $data['permission'] = $this->adminModel->getPermission($suid);

    $checkPermission = $this->adminModel->checkPermission($suid);
    $memrank = $this->adminModel->getMemberRank($suid);

    if(is_array($memrank)) {

            if($memrank['rank'] == 'Super Admin') {

            }
            elseif(isset($checkPermission)) {
                    if($checkPermission['pages'] == 'Not Allowed') {
    
                            return redirect()->back();
    
                    }
            }
    }

    $data['p_data'] = $this->db->table('tblpages')
                                    ->select('*')
                                    ->where(["id" => $id])
                                    ->get()
                                    ->getRow();

    if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {

            $rules = [
                    'p_name' => [

                            'rules' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[250]',
                            'errors' => [
    
                                    'required' => 'You cannot leave this field empty',
                                    'min_length' => 'Title is short',
                                    'max_length' => 'Title is too long',
                            ]
                            ],
                    'p_description' => [
    
                            'rules' => 'required',
                            'errors' => [
    
                                    'required' => 'You cannot leave this field empty',
                            ]
                            ],
            ];

            if($this->validate($rules)) {

                    $pageContent = [

                            'p_name'        => $this->request->getVar('p_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
                            'p_description' =>  htmlentities($this->request->getVar('p_description', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)),
                            'p_slug'        => strtolower(url_title($this->request->getVar('p_name'))),

                    ];

                    if($this->pageModel->updateContent($pageContent, $id)) {

                            $this->session->setTempdata('success', 'Page updated successfully', 3);
                            return redirect()->to(base_url()."/admin/pages");

                    } else {

                            $this->session->setTempdata('error', 'Oops! could not update the page', 3);
                            return redirect()->to(current_url());

                    }
                    

            } else {

                    $data['validation'] = $this->validator;

           }

    } 

    echo view("team/Templates/header_panel");
    echo view("team/navigation", $data);
    echo view("team/sidebar", $data);
    echo view("team/editpage", $data);
    echo view("team/Templates/footer_panel");
    
}
```

**Edit - Create Page View File**

```
<?php

$page_session = \Config\Services::session();

?>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Add New Page</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>/admin">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>/admin/pages">Page List</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Add New Page</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>

    <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="contact__form__title">
                        <?php if($page_session->getTempdata('success', 3)) : ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                <?= $page_session->getTempdata('success', 3); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if($page_session->getTempdata('error', 3)) : ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <?= $page_session->getTempdata('error', 3); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="card card-primary">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-pills nav-fill">
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a href="#details" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">Add Page</a>
                                        </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="tab-content">
                                                <div id="details" class="tab-pane active">
                                                                <?= form_open('admin/addPage/'); ?>
                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                                                <?= csrf_field(); ?>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                                                <label for="pTitle">Edit Title</label>
                                                                                <input type="text" name="p_name" value="<?= set_value('p_name'); ?>" class="form-control" id="pTitle" placeholder="Page Name or Page Title" required>
                                                                                <span class="text-danger"><?= display_errors($validation, 'p_name'); ?></span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                                                <label for="pContent">Edit Page Content</label>
                                                                                <textarea id="editor" name="p_description" class="form-control" id="pContent" cols="10" rows="10" placeholder="Write something here.." required><?= set_value('p_description'); ?></textarea>
                                                                                <span class="text-danger"><?= display_errors($validation, 'p_description'); ?></span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Page</button>
                                                                                <a href="<?= base_url();?>/admin/pages" class="btn btn-dark text-white">Cancel</a>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                        <?= form_close(); ?>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

**init.js file - TinyMCE code to initiate the editor**

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#editor',
  valid_elements : '*[*]',
});
```

**Edited the addPage controller code - Still doesn't work**

```
if(!$this->validate([

                'p_name'        => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[250]',
                'p_description' => 'required',
        ])){
                echo view("team/Templates/header_panel");
                echo view("team/navigation", $data);
                echo view("team/sidebar", $data);
                echo view("team/addpage", $data);
                echo view("team/Templates/footer_panel");
        }
        else {
                if($this->pageModel->save) {(
                        [
                                'p_name'        => $this->request->getVar('p_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
                                'p_description' => $this->request->getVar('p_description'),
                                'p_date'        => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
                                'p_slug'        => strtolower(url_title($this->request->getVar('p_name'))),

                        ]

                );

                        $this->session->setTempdata('success', 'Page Created successfully', 3);
                        return redirect()->to(base_url()."/admin/pages");

                }
                else {

                        $this->session->setTempdata('error', 'Unable to create page', 3);
                        return redirect()->to(current_url());

                }
        }
```

**Model for this entire code**

```
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class PageModel extends Model {

        protected $table = 'tblpages';
        protected $allowedFields = ['p_name', 'p_description', 'p_date', 'p_slug'];

        public function getPages($slug = null) {
                
                if(!$slug) {

                        return $this->findAll();
                }

                return $this->asArray()
                            ->where(['p_slug' => $slug])
                            ->first();
        }

        public function updateContent($pageContent, $id) {

                $builder =  $this->db->table('tblpages');
                $builder->where('id', $id);
                $result = $builder->update($pageContent);

                if($this->db->affectedRows() > 0) {

                        return true;

                } else {

                        return false;
                }
        }

        // Delete Page
        public function deletePage($id) {

                $builder = $this->db->table('tblpages');
                $builder->where('id', $id);
                $builder->delete();
                
        }
}
```

Please help me on this one. Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the culprit in both controllers

```php
'p_description' => htmlentities($this->request->getVar('p_description', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
```

According to [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING:

> Strip tags and HTML-encode double and single quotes, optionally strip or encode special characters.

Since you want to keep the HTML markup, simply remove the FILTER_SANITIZE_STRINGS filter and you should be good to go.

Another problem with your view file is that your text editor has two id's: `editor1 and` pContent`

```html
<textarea id="editor" name="p_description" class="form-control" id="pContent" cols="10" rows="10" placeholder="Write something here.." required><?= set_value('p_description'); ?></textarea>
```

Remove the extra id, and everything should be fine.

*Edit about the create code not working*
In your addPage controller, I noticed this:

```php
if($this->pageModel->save) {([
    'p_description' => ...,
])
}
```

Note that that's not the same as

```php
if($this->pageModel->save([
    'p_description' => '...',
])) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Could you show your tinyMCE html tags?

Comment: Also @Praise i am still unable to insert data with tinyMCE editor, although the solution worked for updating data

Comment: @KaustubhShinde you mean that when you submit data for the first time (create a page), nothing is received from the tinyMCE text area right? That would mean that the tinyMCE data isn't a part of the request or you're accessing it wrongly. Edit your question and include a snippet of your view files so I can have a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: @praise dare done!

Comment: @KaustubhShinde I editted my answer according to your new feeback.

Comment: @PraiseDare I tried your solution it didn't work so modified the addPage function and i have even shared the Model code (Still did not work). Although i do have one question in editPage view file same mistake was their( i.e 2 ids for textarea) but still it worked and how come it created problem while inserting the content? PS. i know its quite weird issue but your help will be appreciable..

Comment: @PraiseDare it was a Javascript validation conflict i just have to remove "required" from the textarea input and it worked! but "required" was also there in edit page still it was submitting the data only at add page i had to remove it weird.. anyways thanks for help!